# Why my MySQL version vary?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Why I have 2 versions? I've upgraded to 5.6 recently yet seeing 5.5.35 there as well.

`mysql -u user -p` > Server version: 5.6.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

`mysql -V` > mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

```
~$ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql

~$ whereis mysql
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/bin/X11/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

Comment: Have you restarted mysqld since installing the update?

Comment: yeah, if i didnt how you would do it

Comment: Something like `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart`.  I don't know if this will fix it, but it might.

Comment: I've did it as wall as resetig via `service` and it all went thru.

Comment: upgrade mysql client to  5.6.15 and try

Answer (score 0):

you likely have different mysql version packages (mysql-common, mysql-client, ...)

try

```
> which mysql
> whereis mysql
```

Comment: Updaten my answer to address that.